# how to properly check expiration time of renewable in app subscription in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, subscription

i'm developing application with in app subscriptions (monthly, yearly). When i'm getting the receipt from apple with response (i'm validating receipt with apple server, i know this is not a good idea, but still), i want to check the expiration date of the subscription. Here's the checking part.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *expireDate = receipt[@"expires_date"];
NSComparisonResult result = [currentDate compare:expireDate];
BOOL subscribed = (result != NSOrderedDescending);
```

But if the device time is wrong(the user changed the time of the device) how can i be sure that subscription is still active ? Maybe i should request the current time from the server ?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reading up a little more about [Apple's receipt verification](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2) and how most effectively validate In-App Purchases.

> To your question: In short, **yes.** Requesting the current time from a server will give you the current time *independent* from the users device. This will **always** be the most reliable way to retrieve the current time.

---

**A little more detail...**

---

What you need to do is read the receipt url as data then base 64 encode it from the data. There is a similar post to this question which will be helpful in understanding this process.

Ultimately you need to handle this sensitive data as securely as you can - this process will allow you to retrieve the best kept "safe" expiration date (receipt) for your IAP.

---

[Read this post to help point you in the right direction.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924411/how-to-get-ios-appstorereceipturl-into-base-64-encoded-string/18927587#18927587)

---

In regard to checking the **"correct time"** there are a few approaches you can take here.

**Approach 1** 
Get the correct time from an API. [Here is an API](https://worldtime.io/api/geo) you could use to get the world time. [You could also use AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11414714/4577249) to get the current time.

**Approach 2** 
[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12221777/4577249) goes into a simple way to monitor device clock changes to make sure / listen for the user changing the time. By monitoring for any *large* time changes you can decide whether the user has changed the clock maliciously or not.

Approach 1 will deliver (of course) an independent time for you to compare that *should always* be the true current time, where as 2 is a way that **you** can monitor the device's clock.